# Make javascript execute conditionally based on boolean setting in .properties file

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, properties

Hey using spring tool suite, relatively new in webapps.  I have a big javascript method that I now need to execute conditionally based on a setting that is configured in a .properties file, (ie generateCourseCondition=true). Was wondering what the best way to access this boolean value would be.

Example:

In general.properties

catalogcourse.courseCatalogLinkSwitch=true

Bean definition

`<bean id="plannedCourseController" class="plannedcourse.web.PlannedCourseController" >
    <property name="courseCatalogLinkSwitch"  value="${catalogcourse.courseCatalogLinkSwitch}" />
</bean>`

Controller Setter:

```
public void setCourseCatalogLinkSwitch(boolean courseCatalogLinkSwitch) {
    this.courseCatalogLinkSwitch= courseCatalogLinkSwitch;
}
```

java script

```
if (courseCatalogLinkSwitch (or however I am supposed to access)){
.......
}
```

Any suggestions, similar examples or links would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Is the controller doing any specific operation before sending to a jsp or is it just for accessing the property? Would be good if you can provide more of your controller code.

Comment: No, I think what @taptrick wants is to access that value (in the `.properties` file) directly from the JavaScript context (client's side). If so, that's not possible, at least not in the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the variable to the model and write the javascript variable in the jsp.

```
<script>
  var courseCatalogLinkSwitch = <c:out value="${model.courseCatalogLinkSwitch}" />
</script>
```